# How to find P(2X>4)?

Tags: binomial-distribution

This is a Binomial question. I am required to find P(2X>4), and given that X~B(10,0.2), how do I convert it to 2X~B(n,p)?

Have tried converting from P(2X>4) to P(X>2), but understand that it doesn't work that way.

Do i have to use integration or any formula that i should refer?

Comment: I'm very curious where you read that $P(2X>4)\ne P(X>2)$.

Comment: suppose X is a function for x^2, and 2X will be (2x)^2 = 4(x^2).

Comment: @ming the set of $X$ that makes the event $\{2X>4\}$ true is the same with the set that makes $\{X>2\}$ true, so their probabilities must be equal.

Comment: suppose i want to find 2X~B(n',p') from X~B(10,0.2), what would the values of n' and p' be? how can i work out the values? @gunes

Comment: you can’t because $2X$ is not binomial. If it were, you would be able to get a nonzero probability for $P(2X=1)$, but you can’t.

Comment: hence, if we were asked to find P(2X = 1), it is essentially the same as asking us to find P(X= 1/2)? @gunes

Comment: yea it is the same

Answer (score 1):

$P(X>2)$ actually works (what went wrong?). It is $$P(X>2)=1-P(X\leq 2)=1-\sum_{i=0}^2{10 \choose i}(0.2)^i(0.8)^{10-i}$$